# Split a log file into multiple log files based on a list of IPs

Tags: logging, split, ip-address

I have large log files with lines like this:

> 80.254.145.163 0       POST    -       /01_COMMON/HelpComBase.cab      80             winnt://demo\faith.simmon       211.47.66.172   211.47.66.172   0       200     virus   oi.win32.susp.KP        80.254.145.163  2014-05-01 17:00:44
>   80.254.145.163          0       POST    -       /01_COMMON/HelpComBase.cab      80              winnt://demo\faith.simmon       211.47.66.172   211.47.66.172   0       200     virus   oi.win32.susp.SJ        80.254.145.163  2014-05-01 17:00:34
>   63.251.108.100  RMA/1.0 (compatible; RealMedia) 0       POST    -       /Msg/7.0/win32  80              winnt://demo\abbie.murray       message.real.com        207.188.5.178   0       0       category        Computers and Internet  63.251.108.100  2014-05-01 17:10:46
>   80.254.145.163          0       POST    -       /floodle/12545/carradiodecoders.zip     80              winnt://demo\courtney.car       www.ohrep.com   67.210.120.80   0       200     virus   Trojan.Win32.Agent.djpe 80.254.145.163  2014-05-01 17:10:44
>   63.251.108.100  RMA/1.0 (compatible; RealMedia) 0       POST    -       /Msg/7.0/win32  80              winnt://demo\abbie.murray       message.real.com        207.188.5.178   0       0       category        Computers and Internet  63.251.108.100  2014-05-01 17:11:52

I want to be able to split this log into multiple logs based on a list of IPs.  For example all lines with the IP "80.254.145.163" would be written to logA.log and "63.251.108.100" would be written to logB.log.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So you have a few options to do this.

Here are two ways of approaching this.

1) Make a wrapper for your python Logger which gets the prefixed IP from your log statement and either writes to a local log file who's name is that IP (80.254.145.163.txt) or creates a new log file using that IP as the file name.

This way you ll have a directory full of log files which just contain log statements regarding that IP.

2) You could use a logging service to forward your logs on and then use the providers Search to just see the relevant logs based on their IP. If you were to go down this route I would (biased) suggest https://logentries.com/.